# Issue with Firebase Dynamic Link in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

This is the created dynamic link, while dynamic link creation.
https://xyz.page.link/r?id=ABCDEFG

But, the problem is when I'm trying to read dynamic link using

```
PendingDynamicLinkData? data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
String url = data?.link.toString();
```

It's giving me incomplete URL only, not the parameters i.e.
https://xyz.page.link/r

I'm using firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.0.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide  query parameters in deep link field while creating firebase dynamic link. Here in your example I can see you have provided id=ABCDEFG in dynamic link itself.
[Dynamic link Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi4i0.png)

[Deeplink Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8AjS.png)

https://xyz.page.link/r?id=ABCDEFG you should insert this in deeplink field. Hope this will help you.

You can create dynamic link using code [Dynamic link Package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links)

```
 Future<String> generateDynamicLink( {
    String? title,
    String? description,
    Uri? thumbnail,
  }) async {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks dynamicLinks = FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;

    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      // uriPrefix: dynamicLinkPrefix,
      uriPrefix: "https://xyz.page.link",
      link: Uri.parse("https://xyz.page.link/r?id=ABCDEFG"),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName:"your package name",
      ),
      googleAnalyticsParameters: const GoogleAnalyticsParameters(
        source: "your source",
        medium: "your medium",
        campaign: "none",
      ),
      iosParameters: IOSParameters(
        appStoreId: appstoreId,
        bundleId:"iosBundleId",
      ),
      socialMetaTagParameters: thumbnail != null
          ? SocialMetaTagParameters(
              imageUrl: thumbnail,
              title: title,
              description: description,
            )
          : null,
    );
    final ShortDynamicLink shortLink =
        await dynamicLinks.buildShortLink(parameters);
    Uri uri = shortLink.shortUrl;
    return uri.toString();
  }
```

Comment: I have to create thousands of dynamic links, using this way I won't be able to create, tell me something which can be done using codes

Comment: @GulshanYadav I have updated my answer please have a look

Comment: thanks man, this was the solution, unfortunately I fixed it before your answer, but it will help other developers, so approving your answer